# Workflow Go To Record action setting Customer in a Customer Refund

Tags: netsuite

I have a NetSuite Workflow setup to create a Customer Refund from a Sales Order with a related Customer Deposit. I'm pre-populating most of the fields without any problem.

But there are 2 that will not hold a value, Customer and Payment Method. They always end up being blank.

What's interesting is I set the Memo field to Customer and it does keep the value from the Sales Order without any problem.

What is special about the Customer field so it doesn't keep the same value from the Sales Order and how do I work around the problem?

I also need to set the Payment Method from the Customer Deposit related to the Sales Order.

One final note (I'll probably have to write some script for this) I need to check the Customer Deposit related to the Sales Order in the Apply Deposits area at the bottom of the form.

Thanks,
Russ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the transform action for this and you shouldn't try to pre-populate the customer nor payment method. Those will flow through from the Sales Order. 
If you need to change the payment method after the fact I suspect you'll have to first run the transform action and then update the payment method in another step.

Comment: I like the idea, when I try using a Transform action in the Record Type I see Cash Sale, Invoice, Item Fulfillment and Return Authorization, but Customer Refund is not one of them.

Comment: right you'd have to actually have received the cash first so you'd need to start from the Cash Sale.

Comment: In this case they have received a Customer Deposit that is related to the original Sales Order.

Comment: In that case you'd have to start the refund from the customer and then void the deposit. (or maybe vice versa) This is doable with a script. To keep it in the context of a workflow you'd at least have to create a custom action script.

Comment: I've started writing a custom workflow action script. I'm getting hung up trying to get access to the current record. nlapiGetRecordID() doesn't seem to work in an action script - I received this error message "ReferenceError: "nlapiGetRecordID" is not defined. (ifxCustomerRefund.js$1157783#4)"

Comment: `nlapiGetRecordId()` note that last `d` is in small